# Recursion in JavaScript question- how is the position of console.log here affecting the order in which values are returned?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callstack

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm learning about basic recursion for the first time. A result I just got playing around with a practice question in JavaScript is really baking my
noodle.

```
function countDownRecursive(n) {
   if (n == 0) {
     console.log('Hooray!')
     return
     } else {
       console.log(n)
       countDownRecursive(n-1)
       console.log(n)               
     }
}
```

The output of ie, countDownRecursive(3) is

> 3 2 1 Hooray! 1 2 3

My question is why does putting console.log() after countDownRecursive(n-1) like this cause JS to log the values in reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the initial call, the `else` is entered, and

```
   console.log(n)
   countDownRecursive(n-1)
```

3 is logged. Then, the initial `countDownRecursive(3)` function being suspended while `countDownRecursive(3-1)` is called. The stack is now composed of `countDownRecursive(3)`.

The same thing happens with `countDownRecursive(2)`. 2 is logged, and with *its* recursive call, the stack is now composed of `countDownRecursive(2)` and `countDownRecursive(3)`.

And so on. At the end, with `countDownRecursive(0)`, the stack is

```
countDownRecursive(0) <-- current function
countDownRecursive(1)
countDownRecursive(2)
countDownRecursive(3)
```

and `3 2 1` has been logged.

At 0, there's no more recursion, so there's `Hooray`. That innermost `countDownRecursive(0)` ends, and then the `countDownRecursive(1)` resumes at the point at the point of the recursive call:

```
   countDownRecursive(1-1) // this line just finished
   console.log(1)
```

so 1 gets logged, and that function ends.

The functions keep resuming, logging, and exiting, until the stack is empty, and you're left with logs of

```
3
2
1
Hooray!
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a little while to get it. So the function call of countDownRecursive(n) executes up through countDownRecursive (n -1) and is suspended. This repeats until n – 1 == 0, at which point console.log(‘Hooray’) is returned. So we get 3 2 1 Hooray!
Then each function call resumes. Since JS’s call stack uses a Last In First Out method of execution, countDownRecursive(1) resumes first.  The only part of each function call left to execute is the bottom-most console.log(n). So we get 1 2 3. 
So seen in the console, the final output is 3 2 1 Hooray! 1 2 3
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, when you call a function while within another, the original function is suspended while the called function runs. The chain can go on for a long time before the original function resumes.

Comment: I realize I was failing to really grasp that when JavaScript suspends a function, it executes it up until the point at which the nested function is called before suspending it, and that only the unexecuted part stays on the call stack. And with recursion, this happens as many times as a recursive function is called. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)